# Sum with Calculation from Sub-Document items

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have invoice Model as following

```
{
...

"itemDetails": [
            {
                "item":  "593a1a01bbb00000043d9a4c",
                "purchasingPrice": 100,
                "sellingPrice": 150,
                "qty": 200,
                "_id": "59c39c2a5149560004173a05",
                "discount": 0
            }
        ],
        "payments": [],
...

}
```

I need to calculate item-vice total sum or selling price - discount.

I saw `$sum` operator but couldn't find a way to group with `item._id`

Comment: Group or per array item? Because `"item._id"` implies you mean for each array item.

Comment: I will have many invoices and each of them as itemDetails I need to get item vice sale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to get a total grouped by a property "inside" an array, then you always need [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/). If you need to apply "math" before accumulating via [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/), then use the [math operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-arithmetic/). Such as [`$subtract`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/) in this case:

```
Model.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$itemDetails" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$itemDetails.item",
    "salePrice": { 
      "$sum": {
        "$subtract": [ "$itemDetails.sellingPrice", "$itemDetails.discount" ]
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Presuming of course that `itemDetails.item` is actually common to the items in different invoices.

Comment: it needs to be `"_id":"$itemDetails.item"

Comment: @user2473015 Well it was correct before you [changed the structure in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/46844005/3). You previously had `item` as as sub-document with it's own properties. You really should not change your question like that once there is already an answer, because the context gets lost. You should revert the structure in the question even if you need to change in your real implementation.

Comment: yes. I have added populated structure previously. Sorry for that.